# why does ie8 flash white background for a fraction of a second on refresh?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with IE8. When the age reloads/refreshes it flashes white. My client is very unhappy and I'm unable to find any kind of answer anywhere. PLEASE can anyone shed any light. Here's a link to a site with the issue: http://www.gingergraphicdesign.com

Comment: Also happening with Chrome...

Comment: On a side note, your CSS styles leave a lot to be desired... Are seriously going to leave things called style1, style2, ...style27?

Comment: JohnFly... thank you I really appreciate you pointing out the Chrome issue. You are also correct about the odd style names-as its my own site I don't mind styles being abstrusely named for once-the style names are left over from when I began webdesign at the outset, a long while back, with an html generator. My other sites for clients have proper css style names.

Comment: ps the Ginger site is way way overdue for a rebuild-it just shows the same problem that my client's site suffers from in ie8, is all. I could not post a link to his site as it has logos etc that he has not yet got permission to show and there could be copyright issues.

Comment: Hi
lots of respect tio GenericTypeTea as I say this but to not address a query at all but just offer unsolicited criticism about an unrelated issue does not seem courteous. Please see my comments about age and origin of that site.

Comment: Sorry to John Fly-I misread my screen and my observations about age/origin of site are for GenericTypeTea. Thanks.

Comment: I *think* a similar problem is also reported here with no solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245774/background-images-are-flashing-when-changing-pages-only-in-ie

Answer (score 3):

Your inline CSS says:

```
body { margin:0px; background-color:#fff ...
```

...so that (#fff, e.g., white) is the color that will show up before the other elements show up or the background graphic loads. Pick a color as close in tone and value to the main color of the final loaded version to minimize the apparent flicker. In your case, the majority of the resulting layout is the black-background box, so you want to go with black.

Comment: Thank you-I have done so and what you say is indeed correct though the flicker remains-just goes black instead of white. On my client's site (the Ginger site is just my own old site I'm using to demo the problem) he wants no transitional refresh at all-as though the page has a background colour rather than an image. Your advice however is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @martinjbull: If it's refresh, specifically, that you're worried about, you can always update content *without* refreshing the page, by loading context via Ajax and filling in the relevant container.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of reducing flicker between page transitions in IE is the fajax technique described [here](http://www.secretgeek.net/fajax.asp).

It gives a short transition effect though regardless of the next page visited so might not be suitable but just thought I'd throw it in as a possibility.

```
<META http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.1)">
<META http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.1)">
```

Comment: Thanks-I had tried this before but no success-but this time it works! its possible that your code is different in some way to the code I used last time-I'll compare and see. Thank you.

Comment: This fixed a similar issue I had with IE8. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
body, html{background:#0F0;}
```

Apply the bg to HTML tag.
Success :D

Answer (score 1):

Your page background is #FFFFFF (White).  It is being displayed for just a split second before the image url("Resources/ggdbggradient.gif") is shown.

Change your background color to something darker that matches and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you-I have done so and what you say is indeed correct though the flicker remains-just goes black instead of white. On my client's site (the Ginger site is just my own old site I'm using to demo the problem) he wants no transitional refresh at all-as though the page has a background colour rather than an image. Your advice however is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found setting the background color in the CSS file does not remove the white flash.

What worked for me was inlining the style in the header just before CSS files are loaded. In my case the color I wanted was `#D0D0D0` so this is what I did.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<!-- META Tags -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>html, body { background-color: #D0D0D0; } </style>

<!-- CSS Style Sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>
```

This solved the white flash in IE9 for me. My guess is that IE would draw the page white if there was Javascript to execute in the `<head>`, but IE would not parse the CSS file until it reached the `<body>`.