# Background images are flashing when changing pages - only in IE

Tags: http, browser, cross-browser

In IE9, when changing pages with the same background image, it is 'flashing'. In Firefox changing pages remain smooth, no refreshing or blinking of the background images.

When looking at the http traffic, the header for the images is 304 - so they shouldn't be refreshed. Can I do something about this?

[When you click this link with IE9 you can see the testpage](http://www.vuyk.eu/testsite/test3/testpage1.html)

This is the profile IE Developer F12 makes:
[image]

Comment: Is caching disabled in your ie?

Comment: try with full `url` instead of `relative` path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, caching in IE9 is not disabled, full url is now in stylesheet, it is still flashing.

Comment: There should be something wrong, it is a very obvious reloading of images, very disturbing!!

Comment: Sergio, don't you have the same refreshing of the images?

Comment: I have the same problem for an MVC App of mine.  When I use Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m or IE 10, my background image flashes when going from one page to the next.  When I use FireFox 19.0.2 the problem goes away.  Like Mr. Vuyk, I used the IE10 Network tab and found the 304 response, so I can't understand why IE or Chrome would think that it has to reload the image.

Comment: IE10 doesn't cache image loaded via CSS so image must be loaded explicitly; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18294777/1058320). I'm not sure if this applies to IE9 as well