# IE background flicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have the problem that when I switch to other pages on the site, my background turns white and loads again. I know it has something to do with the IE cache and did some research about it. I already tried the most common fixes, both css and javascript, like the ones on this site: http://ieflicker.com/ but none of them works.

*UPDATE (some code)*

The site uses BODY with  `background-image: url('background1.jpg')` as a part of its CSS. This seems to load image once and cache it in all the browsers but IE10. IE10 seems to reload it every time.

Comment: The best fix IMO is stopping using IE altogether. In my sites people cannot authenticate if they are using IE. Hatred apart, please post your code here if you want help, otherwise someone may think this is actually a scheme to get some people to visit your site. Finally you should look for the causes of flickering specific to IE, like having style tags in your HTML and such.

Comment: When asking IE questions, it's important to specify which IE version(s) you're having issues with. Does it happen in all versions or only specific versions?

Comment: The problems occur with the last version of Internet Explorer (10)

Comment: anyone remember that site that charged 7% tax if you checkout with IE :P (genius!)

Comment: @Renan some people don't have a luxury of not using IE - e.g. enterpises. I agree IE7 and before should not be supported anymore, but IE8+ are pretty much very active these days. And speaking of the code - if you look at the site it's a very basic body style that uses background image - nothing more. And that background flickers on page reload.

Comment: And why is it off topic? It's a problem with CSS not working as expected? If so, I've updated to post line of CSS code that's not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently IE10 doesn't cache image loaded via CSS despite all the hacks. You need to explicitly load it. E.g. if your body style mentions:

```
background-image: url('background1.jpg')
```

add this to your page's HTML:

```
<img src='background1.jpg' style='display:none' />
```

Now *this* will load and cache the image and the flicker will be avoided.

Comment: This also helps on the iPad.